# How to select distinct for one column and any in another column?

Tags: query

I need to query an SQL database to find all distinct values of one column and I need an arbitrary value from another column.  For example, consider the following table with two columns, key and value:

```
key     value
===     =====
one     test
one     another
one     value
two     goes
two     here
two     also
three   example
```

I wish to get back one sample row, chosen arbitrarily, from each distinct key, perhaps getting these three rows:

```
key     value
===     =====
one     test
two     goes
three   example
```

How can I formulate such a query in SQL?

Comment: Which DBMS (Oracle, SQL-Server, DB2, MySQL, Postgres)?

Comment: It is a proprietary system.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The easiest query to write is for MySQL (with not strict ANSI settings). It uses the non-standard construction:

```
SELECT key, value
FROM tableX
GROUP BY key ;
```

In recent version (5.7 and 8.0+) where the strict settings and `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` are the default, you can use the `ANY_VALUE()` function, added in 5.7:

```
SELECT key, ANY_VALUE(value) AS value
FROM tableX
GROUP BY key ;
```

---

For other DBMSs, that have window functions (like Postgres, SQL-Server, Oracle, DB2), you can use them like this. The advantage is that you can select other columns in the result as well (besides the `key` and `value`) :

```
SELECT key, value
FROM tableX
    ( SELECT key, value,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key 
                                ORDER BY whatever)     --- ORDER BY NULL
               AS rn                                   --- for example
      FROM tableX
    ) tmp 
WHERE rn = 1 ;
```

---

For older versions of the above and for any other DBMS, a general way that works almost everywhere. One disadvantage is that you cannot select other columns with this approach. Another is that aggregate functions like `MIN()` and `MAX()` do not work with some datatypes in some DBMSs (like bit, text, blobs):

```
SELECT key, MIN(value) AS value
FROM tableX
GROUP BY key ;
```

---

PostgreSQL has a special non-standard `DISTINCT ON` operator that can also be used. The optional `ORDER BY` is for selecting which row from every group should be selected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (key) key, value
FROM tableX
-- ORDER BY key, <some_other_expressions> ;
```

Comment: @WilliamKF If by "chosen arbitrarily" you mean "chosen randomly" then simply replace the `ORDER BY whatever` in ypercube's query with a call to a function to randomize the results.

Comment: @LeighRiffel It need not be random, any choice, as simple as the first one encountered works fine.

Answer (score 6):

**For MS-SQl Server:**

```
;with FinalDataset as
(
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by key order by value) as rownum
    from YourOriginalTable
)
select
   key,
   value
from FinalDataset 
where rownum = 1
```

Likewise, you could have rownum = 2 for your second result set

Answer (score 2):

Similar to accepted answer, but instead of min() or max() you can use array_agg()

```
SELECT key, (array_agg(value))[1] AS value
FROM tableX
GROUP BY key ;
```

You can optionally order values inside array to select biggest or smallest of them:

```
SELECT key, (array_agg(value) ORDER BY value DESC)[1] AS value
FROM tableX
GROUP BY key ;
```

(checked on PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1):

If you use PostgreSQL, there is also a aggregate function called `first()` (or `last()`) from an extension called [first_last_agg](https://github.com/wulczer/first_last_agg), which does exactly this: returning the first value (in any defined order):

```
SELECT key, first(value) AS value
FROM tab
GROUP BY key ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the query below :

```
select key, value
  from (select key,
               value,
               row_number() over(partition by key order by value) rnum
          from YourOriginalTable )
 where rnum = 1;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't meet the "one sample row, chosen arbitrarily" requirement. And it is not "PLSQL".

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for your practical and informative comment. I will delete my answer but before that , could you please explain more how it does not meet the "one sample row" , chosen "arbitrary" ?

Comment: @mustaccio . Another thing is that "JP Chauhan" answer is similar to mine. Isn't it? so in what way exactly my way is different from his? Thanks in advance