# Select one item per matching ids(value)

Tags: mysql, query, greatest-n-per-group

I have a mysql table(trips) with records about cars. I wish to query the data and return one item per carId. But am unable. Below is the query example getting 50 records, which should also have 50 carId

```
SELECT * 
FROM `trips` 
WHERE (   carId = 147 
       OR carId = 62 
       OR carId = 59 
       OR carId = 42) 
LIMIT 50
```

Below is an example that returns 8 records. How to return limit 8 records but one record per car. [Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=67a7ed1b3c130b9735cf60bdd3dbe88c)

Comment: If you need "return one item per carId" then the amount of selected records cannot exceed 4. `LIMIT 50` is strange...

Comment: Specify MySQL version. Specify your SQL mode. Provide the criteria which allows to select one specific record from a lot of records with the same `carId`.

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a [repro] with the table definitions and sample data to better define the question. [Start here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5996bac59fddf9bb0942b34c066cac31) and edit as necessary until you can provide the actual output you are seeing locally.

Comment: Peter Vandivier, I added some sample data

Comment: HINT: `GROUP BY`, `SUM()`

Comment: please check similar question with a great answer - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24327/how-to-select-distinct-for-one-column-and-any-in-another-column

Comment: @Nikita - that would mean turning ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY off - which is **not** a good idea - like your input though! To the OP, your example on the fiddle (**thanks** for that!), you have trips of `id` = 1 and cars of `id`s 59 and 42 duplicated. Surely, trip_id and car_id together should be a `PRIMARY KEY`? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Which record per car do you want to return? The first according to some order?

Comment: Look into the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) Window Function

Comment: Groupwise-max;  see the added tag.  Though you are not looking for the max of each, you still need the techniques embodied there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `trips` 
WHERE carId in (147, 62, 59, 42) 
GROUP by carId;
```

Remove the **LIMIT** and be sure that you get **one row per carId**. If you put 20 ids within in ( ), you will get 20 exclusive rows.

But this gives a rough result in the sense that it might choose **any one row matching the carId**. You might add some condition to pickup any preferred row per **carId**.

Comment: The `OR` is turned into `IN` in this example.